# Obtain CSS animation id from Chrome dev tools in headless mode with PHP webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, animation, webdriver, devtools

I am writing a series of automated tests on a web page that includes CSS keyframe animations using PHP webdriver (https://php-webdriver.github.io/php-webdriver/latest/Facebook/WebDriver/Chrome/ChromeDevToolsDriver.html). My goal is to use the Chrome Dev Tools API to interact with the "Animation" domain to be able to seek the animations to a specific timecode and then validate the CSS of the elements. I know how to seek an animation thanks to the documentation found at https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Animation/. However, the API continually refers to the "id" as a required parameter and I can't find any way to obtain the id for any animation.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. I tried writing `document.getAnimations()` to the console. In a live browser, it works, but the "id" property of the returned animation object is empty. In the headless mode, it always returns an empty object.
2. I can see the animation ids listed in the "Protocol Monitor" in the live browser after I open the "Animations" tab, and I can see events like `Animation.animationCreated` and `Animation.animationStarted` that return an object containing the animation id. However, I can't find a way to capture those Dev Tool events and get the id. So far the only way I've been able to see anything like that is in the Dev Tools of a full browser (non-headless).
3. I was able to get the actual content of the keyframes animations using the Dev Tools API to get the `nodeId` of the element that has the animation, and then using the `CSS.getMatchedStyleForNode` to return the keyframe information. However, that doesn't actually tell me if the animations are running and I can't track the changes in the CSS over the length of the animation.
4. I tried using JavaScript to get the styles by adding event listeners to the element with the animation for the `animationstart` and `animationend` events. The `animationstart` event listener works just fine, but the `animationend` event never fires. The `animation-iteration-count` is set to infinite, but even when I change that, it still never fires.

Any assistance or guidance is greatly appreciated.